# Idiom for putting in too much effort

Tags: idiom-requests

I‘m looking for an idiom which describes that I put too much engagement/pressure in a thing ( a relationship for example) which eventually blew it.

Answer (score 1):

One fairly common expression is *trying too hard*.

For example usages, it's not too hard to find advice columns entitled something like:

> ***8 Signs You're [Trying Too Hard](https://dailypositiveinfo.com/8-signs-youre-trying-too-hard-to-make-a-relationship-work/) To Make A Relationship Work***
>
> ***10 Signs You’re [Trying Too Hard](http://www.gurl.com/2014/05/17/signs-youre-trying-too-hard-dating-turning-him-off/#1) and Turning Him Off***
>
> ***13 Signs You Are [Trying Too Hard](https://www.bustle.com/articles/167551-13-signs-you-are-trying-too-hard-in-a-relationship) In A Relationship***

Comment: There is even a horrendous noun for this now : https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=try-hard

Answer (score 0):

To **overdo it**:

> *To do so much of an activity that it becomes harmful, detrimental,
>   unenjoyable, or undesirable.* ([the Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/overdo+it))

Examples:

1. I know you're keen to get back into the gym, but don't overdo it or you'll end up hurting yourself.
2. Don't overdo it with loving affection.
3. Don't overdo it, or the search engines might mark down your results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[zealous](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/zealous)**:

> (adj) filled with or inspired by intense enthusiasm or zeal; ardent; fervent

or in your example, **[overzealous](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/overzealous)**:

> (adj) excessively enthusiastic

Answer (score 0):

**too much of a good thing** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/too+much+of+a+good+thing) idiom

> An excessive, unhelpful, or harmful amount of something that is
>   otherwise enjoyable or beneficial.

As in:

I usually take short vacations as I can't stand **too much of a good
thing**.

and

Again a relationship failed. I guess i do not do well with **too much of a good thing!**